# Symfony messenger can't consume messages

Tags: php, symfony, amqp, symfony-messenger

Few weeks ago I set up a Message system with Symfony Messenger and it worked great.

Today I wanted to create new object through message, so I went to my server and type the command to consume message

First I had this result

```
$ bin/console messenger:consume-messages amqp_notifications
/usr/bin/env: ‘php\r’: No such file or directory
```

It never happened before with my files, and I never changed the line ending or encoding of my file sin PHPstorm.

I tried to use `$ php bin/console messenger:consume-messages amqp_notifications`
but then I had this error.

```
  Attempted to load class "AMQPConnection" from the global namespace.
  Did you forget a "use" statement?
```

Pretty weird, because I have have the php-amqp ext installed as you can see on the screenshot of my phpinfo
[image]

I didn't change anything in my Message class or Handler.

Also, I tried to call `new AMQPConnection()` on a random action, just to try, and I didn't get the error.

I'm completely lost with this error this time, as everything is installed.

I use PHP 7.3.1 and symfony Messenger 4.2.2

Comment: Are you sure your CLI and httpd are using the same php version? Try calling `php -v` and `php -i` from the command line and ensure your CLI has the php-amqp extension loaded aswell.

Comment: I don't see `amqp` with `php -i`... I updated from 7.3.0 to 7.3.1 and both cli and httpd were upgraded, so I thought it was the same version.  I added the `extension=amqp` line in the cli php.ini and it worked. weird, I didn't had to do that when I installed php 7.1 or 7.2. and weaird too that mongo ext is loaded when there is no `extension=mongo` in the cli ini. Thanks a lot for that problem. About the `/usr/bin/env: ‘php\r’: No such file or directory` do you have an idea why it came suddenly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your second issue was already solved by [ccKep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1179287/cckep) on his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54450836/symfony-messenger-cant-consume-messages#comment-95710346).

The first one is that the specific shebang line `#!/usr/bin/env php` executes the first php found in the $PATH. So if you already have uninstalled it, which seems the case, or it has a symbolic link to another php version, you can get a wrong result.

Tries to check what is inside the $PATH and replace the PHP path for the correct one. You might get the place running `which php`.

Comment: Hmm, indeed in my PATH I have the folowing (for my user) : `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`. I looked in these folders, in `/usr.bin`, I have multiple php (`php`, `php7.2` and `php7.3`) When I installed php7.3, I did a purge for php7.2, but seems there is still traces. How I can solve that ?

Comment: I would check which PHP is been executed by your webserver, and then there are two alternatives:

1. You can change shebang on the bin/console file to the absolute path of the PHP

2. Create a symlink to the PHP version you want
`sudo ln -s {absolute-path-of-the-php-you-want} /usr/local/bin/php`

This will replace the php executed to the one you want.

Comment: OKay I'll take a look at that. If I remember both `php -v` and `php7.3 -v` returned the same thing though, so I think it's already the same. I'll check what there is in my `bin/console` file and recreate a symlink from `/usr/bin/php7.3` to `/usr/bin/php` to make sure. Will keep you in touch if I have more problem. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Tired to change the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/php` but I got this error `-bash: bin/console: /usr/bin/php^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` the `/usr/bin/php` is valid, I cans do `/usr/bin/php -v` without problem.

Comment: Ok, got the issue. It seems your file is using DOS line endings (CRLF), and possibly I believe you are trying to execute the script from some unix terminal. Try to change the end of the line to LF. I don't know if you use some IDE, but PHP Storm or Notepad++ can solve it easily by an option in their bottom bar.

Comment: Yeah I tried to change all my files to LF few hours ago and now I came back It seems to be working. really weird I didn't had this problem before and weird that git didn't detect the CRLF and warn me.